# Include scripts/styles only once in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

OctoberCMS has a very convenient feature that allows to inject scripts or styles using {% put scripts %} in pages or partials. The problem I am facing is that each time I include a partial that contains this it duplicates the added scripts.

Is there a feature that you can set in order to put scripts only once?

A typical use case that I am facing is with a slider partial that I only want to load its scripts and styles when its actually used in the displayed page, but if I have multiple sliders then I dont want to include the scripts multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solution, you can use any of them, which is well suited for you.

> **1. you can give your script `unique id` to check if its already exist or not and based on that include it**

We make 2 scripts

1. **check-script**  will check if main script is added or not if not
   added add it, OR if already there skip to add.
2. your **main script**

`check-script.js`

```
window.scriptIncluded = document.getElementById('script-included');

// check if script is already loaded if not include it
if(!window.scriptIncluded) {

    scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.id = 'script-included'; // <- USE YOUR ID HERE ITS JUST FOR DEMO
    scriptTag.src = '/plugins/.../assets/bundle.js';

    // add script first time
    document.head.append(scriptTag);
}
```

now in your `{% put scripts %}` just include this script

```js
{% put scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plugin/.../js/check-script.js"></script>
{% endput %}
```

yes `check-script.js` may be include multiple time but, it will load your main script only once.

> **2. better solution would be to add script from your component file and check there**

```php
public function onRun()
{    
    // if global variable is not set only then include script
    if(!isset($GLOBALS['script-included'])) { // <- USE YOUR ID HERE ITS JUST FOR DEMO

        $this->addJs('/plugins/.../assets/main-script.js');

        // set global variable so next time script will not be included
        $GLOBALS['script-included'] = true;
    }
}
```

if any doubt please comment.